# How to search for an element on a Gtree (glib)?

Tags: c, data-structures, glib

So I have a `Gtree` which every node is a struct:

```
typedef struct user {
    int id;
    char username[256]; 
    int post_count; 
    char short_bio[16384]; 
    int reputation;
}*USER;
```

And a GTree:

```
GTree* users;
```

What I want to do now is, once I have an `ID` I want to search on my `Gtree* users` to see if there is an User with the same `ID` as that I pass, if there is I want to increment the `post_count` variable and stop searching.

Example:

```
I pass to the function id=3 and it searches on the GTree for 
a User with id=3 and increments 1 on post_count, using GLIB; 

void increment (GTree* a,int id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation it looks like `g_tree_lookup` is a function which you need. It would find a value according to the passed `gconstpointer key`:

> ```
> g_tree_lookup ()
> gpointer
> g_tree_lookup (GTree *tree,
>                gconstpointer key);
> ```
>
> Gets the value corresponding to the given key. Since a GTree is
>   automatically balanced as key/value pairs are added, key lookup is
>   O(log n) (where n is the number of key/value pairs in the tree).

The code would be similar to:

```
  void increment (GTree* a, int id)
  {
      gpointer ptr = g_tree_lookup (a,  &id);   // search the tree and find the value

      struct user *u = (struct user *) ptr; // cast the `gpointer ` to your pointer to your value 

      if(u){
          u->post_count++;  // increment the post_count
      }
  }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: error: typedef ‘u’ is initialized (use __typeof__ instead).   error: expected expression before ‘typedef’   error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘ptr’      error: expected expression before ‘u’ @sg7

Comment: @Bruno I have not compiled the code.  The `typedef` is not needed.